# Terminology for a 1-d summary of a high-dimensional space?

Tags: data-transformation, econometrics, terminology, descriptive-statistics, function

Overly pedantic question ahead.

Suppose I have a huge matrix `M` that has a row for everyone who was at Disneyland on some particular date, a column for the person's gender, another column for the person's age, and a third column for the amount the person spent on food on that day.

Let `X` be the sum of all spend from 40-year-old males at Disneyland on that day. That is, we're filtering `M` to only contain rows where the first column's value is `male` and the second column's value is `40`, and then we're summing over all values of the third column.

Let `Y` be something similar, but for 40-year-old females.

What is the appropriate term for transformations like `X` and `Y`? I've been calling them "summary statistics", but I guess it's not actually a "statistic", since the function is applied to all values in the population. Would you call this a "summary parameter"? I've never heard that phrase.

Similarly, say I also have 20 of these matrices, each representing Disneyland food purchases for a sample day in October. I then compute the mean X and mean Y values across those days. What would you call that? A summary statistic of a summary parameter?

I gave the "Disneyland" example because the context of my actual problem is also summarizing market outcomes (through a similar filtering-then-summing procedure), so I want to make sure I catch any terminology that might be specific to that particular use-case.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard expression,  or a need for one. Such a reduction of the data (itself a phrase once much more common than data analysis) could be described as yielding  group or aggregate summaries, or any other similar term. People within particular software user communities come to think of such calculations using the name of the routine, function or command that does the work. That eases communication within communities but risks being obscure across them. So in Stata forums we might talk about a `collapse` given the command of that name. If that seems odd outside Stata....

Comment: I would not recommend "summary parameter". Although often used loosely to mean any property or variable, for statistical people a parameter is part of a model and is the term for discussing estimation (and inference more generally). What you discuss is descriptive statistics (and more than fine). Summary statistics sounds perfectly acceptable. A statistic comes from a sample, and that's what you have.